# Solving $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to solve $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$.

I'm interesting in solving this for $x$ by any method. For now I can only do it by sketching the graph.

Also I'd be grateful if anyone could remind me the method whereby we write $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le 0$ and $0 \le x \le 1$ and then use maximum and minimum function. It was something like $a \le x+y \le b$ and $c \le x-y \le d$ and then using maximum and minimum function e.g. $\max(a, c) \le x \le \min(b, d).$

Comment: What do you mean by "solving this for $x$"?  $x$ can be any value in the interval $[0, 1]$, and one can find a satisfactory region for $y$.

Comment: @BrianTung as in I want to bound $x$ by $y$, as in $f(y) \le x \le g(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial solution.** Keep in mind that $y \leq 0$, then square all terms to get

$$
1-x^2 \geq y^2 \geq 0
$$

where the inequalities are reversed because we are squaring non-positive values.  Then the first inequality can be rewritten as

$$
x^2 \leq 1-y^2
$$

and one can use $0 \leq x \leq 1$ to complete the solution.